# Django not recognizing my Token?

Tags: django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django Rest Framework on the backend and an ember-cli app on the frontend. The authentication is working correctly, but there seems to be a hole somewhere in authorization.

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

# views.py
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    "get the data for the current authenticatd user"
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username)
        return queryset

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I make a request to this endpoint `/v1/me/` it responds back with a 403. When I take off the permission class, I get back `{"id":null,"username":"","is_active":false}` because it doesn't know who I am.

Also, when I use the browsable API, the `/v1/me` URL works correctly.

On the Ember side of things, I login with my account and correctly get back my Token. In the request the `Authorization: Token asdf1234asdf1234asdf1234` is being passed. I would think Django takes that token and knows who I am? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
from rest_framework import authentication
class TokenAuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
```

Then,

```
class CurrentUserView(TokenAuthView)
```

Comment: well there is no TokenGETAuthentication, but I added that authentication class and it works. I don't know why though because that's supposedly my default auth class and should be applied automatically?

Comment: I copy pasted it from my system which i renamed :).updated

Answer (score 0):

In the setting you need to add auth_token.

```
# settings.py
   INSTALLED_APP = ('rest_framework.authtoken',)
```

You don't need to add the authentication_classes on every view.